# Error in scheduling R script

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

We are trying to schedule an R script using windows task scheduler.

- location of R `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\R.exe`
- Location of my script `D:\K-exercise\k-demo.R`

These are the steps that we are following:

> Task scheduler--Actions--new--program script--location of cmd.exe--arguments--"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "D:\K-exercise\k-demo.R"--triggered the time

Command prompt is opening but is not sure whether the script it is running or not?
We are not able to see any output.
Can someone help here?

Comment: Try running `Rscript`. You should get an output of the run. Better yet, write a script that will handle output and save whatever you're doing to a specific file.

Comment: I agree with @RomanLuštrik You should use `RScript`. `R CMD BATCH` is only there for historical backward compatibility, AFAIK.